# I cannot remove stopper & rocker-arm assembly completely from bathtub drain

Tags: plumbing

Despite the position of the overflow lever, I cannot remove the articulating assembly entirely. In the past if I messed with it enough it would slide out. What am I doing wrong this time?  Obviously I'm trying to plunge a slow draining tub again...

Answer (score 1):

An accumulation of hard water deposits and anything else that washed through the drain is probably binding it's removal. Pour some CLR or Lime-away into the overflow opening. After awhile chase it with hot water. It could also be that any articulating pieces aren't lining up to allow the arms to be removed. If the sections are hinged they need to pivot at a 90 degree angle to the tub face.

Comment: Thanx for your response-tried all ur suggestions but no luck-at90 degrees to face of tub articulating pieces seem loose but last piece doesn't, have room to turn up & out-I'm stumped. I plunged right over stopper,etc. & junk shot out of overflow & it drains great for now-just know its a temp fix-I guess plumber next-thanx again